# ASP.NET Framework - How to resolve WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks

I have an old project in ASP.NET Framework-4.8, I am given this API to consume. It is a GET Request, with JSON Request and Response.
I want to consume the API using HttpClient GET Request.

URL:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="GetTransactionUrl" value="https://thirdpartyapi/QueryEntries/{trans_ref}"/>
</appSettings>
```

I got this error:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Service.SingleTransferStatusRequest(String TransRef) in c:\Service.cs:line 385

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

When I debugged and put breakpoints, it points at this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiBaseTransactionStatusUrl).Result;
```

Kindly help resolve the problem.

**MAIN CODE:**

**DTO:**

```
public class TransferResponse
{
    public String TransRef { get; set; }
    public String TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public String ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public String ResponseText { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ApiTransferResponseDto
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public bool hasError { get; set; }
    public class Payload
    {
        public string responseStatus { get; set; }
        public string msgId { get; set; }
        public string batch { get; set; }
        public string extTnxReference { get; set; }
        public object isReversed { get; set; }
        public string postingReference { get; set; }
        public string responseStatusDesc { get; set; }
        public string responseStatusCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Service Layer:**

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private string apiBaseSingleStatusUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueryTransactionUrl"];

    [WebMethod]
    public TransferResponse TransferStatusService(String TransRef)
    {
        TransRef = Server.HtmlEncode(TransRef).AlphaNumeric();
        TransferResponse resp = new TransferResponse();
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Add headers if needed
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // Define the API endpoint URL with the TransRef parameter
                string apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl = apiBaseSingleStatusUrl + TransRef;
                // Send the GET request to the API
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl).Result;
                // Check if the response was successful
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Read the response content as a string
                    string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    //string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    // Parse the JSON response
                    var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiTransferResponseDto>(apiResponse);
                    if (responseData.payload != null && responseData.payload.responseStatus == "SUCCESS")
                    {
                        ...

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resp.ResponseText = "INVALID";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    resp.ResponseText = "API Request Failed";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            resp.ResponseCode = "8003";
            resp.ResponseText = ex.Message;
            return resp;
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - when dealing with http requests, avoid using .Result from Task (it may cause deadlocks and other issues) - http client methods are usually async, so the best way is to change method signature to

```
public async Task<TransferResponse> TransferStatusService(String TransRef)
```

Then you could use await keyword while sending requests like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl);
```

If you can't use async and await, at least use this instead of .Result property:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Still not as good as async await, but far better than using .Result.

By looking at this line

```
<add key="GetTransactionUrl" value="https://thirdpartyapi/QueryEntries/{trans_ref}"/>
```

and your service layer, I see mismatch between name of key:

```
 private string apiBaseSingleStatusUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueryTransactionUrl"];
```

One is GetTransactionUrl and second is QueryTransactionUrl - not sure if it's just old piece of code and you have it correctly now, but I wanted to mention that.

However if you would use

```
 <add key="GetTransactionUrl" value="https://thirdpartyapi/QueryEntries/{trans_ref}"/>
```

with your apiBaseLine

```
string apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl = apiBaseSingleStatusUrl + TransRef;
```

with the setup like in your question, you would actually produce string something like

```
string apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl = "https://thirdpartyapi/QueryEntries/{trans_ref}123";
```

Back to your error - try to use async/await, or at least GetAwaiter().GetResult(). Next thing I would try it it wouldn't work is solution mentioned here: [httpclient.GetAsync: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089849/httpclient-getasync-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-o?rq=2)

Comment: I dont want to use async, so I am following this:  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();     So, do I need to change this:  string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: the same still comes up here:     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionStatusUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: There is not a valid reason to not want to use Async. You don't have to treat it as such, but you should still use the workflow and simply .wait() or await the task immediately so that you don't continue forward.

Comment: @ssedlacek - I do I replicate it for a POST Request